# Can we set bar labels with dynamic custom array in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I think this is bug in the library.
I want a custom labels on each bar, but it is not working!

```js
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  plotOptions: {

    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.series.options.myLabels) {
            return "XXX: " + this.series.options.myLabels[this.point.x];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },


  exporting: {
    url: 'http://export.highcharts.com/',
    chartOptions: {
      yAxis: {
        labels: {
          style: {
            color: 'green'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      },
      format: '{value:,.0f}'
    }
  },
  series: [{
      type: 'column',
      data: [10000, 20000, 8000],
      myLabels: ["A", "B", "C"]
    }, {
      type: 'column',
      data: [10000, 2000, 10000]
    }, {
      type: 'spline',
      data: [5000, 15000, 5000]
    }

  ]
};

var globals = {
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ','
  }
}

$('#export').click(function() {
  var obj = {},
    exportUrl = options.exporting.url;
  obj.options = JSON.stringify(options);
  obj.globaloptions = JSON.stringify(globals);
  obj.type = 'image/png';
  obj.async = true;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: exportUrl,
    data: obj,
    success: function(data) {
      var imgContainer = $("#imgContainer");
      $('<img>').attr('src', exportUrl + data).attr('width', '450px').appendTo(imgContainer);

    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="export">get image</button>
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jm463mwr/1/

Comment: included code from JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a bug, because you cannot place the function inside the json. Functions are not executable and are skipped. So you need to use the callback and there place your function in `series.update()`;

Fixed demo:
- http://jsfiddle.net/ayyunrb4/